# How to prove $\dim((\operatorname{null}\varphi_1)\cap\ldots\cap(\operatorname{null}\varphi_m))=(\dim V)-m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

May I please ask how to prove the following statement:

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_m$ is a linearly independent list in $V^*$. Then

$\dim((\operatorname{null}\varphi_1)\cap\ldots\cap(\operatorname{null}\varphi_m))=(\dim V)-m$

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I'm pretty sure the author means $V^*$ instead of $V'$

Comment: @user2520938 That would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map
$$\theta: V\to \mathbb{R}^m: v\mapsto (\phi_1(v), \dots, \phi_m(v))$$
after chosing a basis, $\theta$ is can be represented by a $m\times \dim V$ matrix $A$. from the rank-nullity theorem we know that 
$$rk(A)+\dim nul(A) = \dim V$$
now $rk(A) = m$, since the $\phi_i$ are independent, and $nul(A) = nul(\phi_i)\cap\dots\cap nul(\phi_m)$. This gives the result.